# What does indirect lending mean?

Tags: terminology, financing, lending

I found a webpage for a credit union that says that they do indirect lending. I can't understand the process.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

[Indirect lending](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/indirect-loan.asp) is simply a loan where the lender does not have a direct relationship with the borrower.  This is often seen at car dealerships: A buyer comes in to purchase a car, and the salesperson talks to the buyer about financing.  The car dealership itself isn't actually in the lending business, but the salesperson does all the paperwork and sets up the loan between the borrower and the lender to facilitate the purchase of the car.  The dealership is then able to sell the car, and usually gets a sales commission from the lender for "selling" the loan.  The lender then profits from the interest on the loan.